# Meter un echo dentro de otro

Tags: php, html

No se si la pregunta es correcta así, pero es como la entiendo. Estoy haciendo la parte de mostrar la web en distintos idiomas y tengo que imprimir `echo` de este modo `<?php echo viviendasDisposicion; ?>`

Pero claro en mi plantilla tengo partes de este modo:

```
echo "<a href=\"detalle-vivienda.php?ID=$viID\" class=\"botonMasInfo\">MÁS INFO</a>";
```

Donde pone `MÁS INFO` tengo que meter el echo pero no se muy bien como.

**Edito para explicarlo mejor**

La variable `$viID` no da ningún tipo de problema eso funciona perfecto.Lo que pasa que al estar imprimiendo el idioma de este modo `<?php echo anadidosRecientes; ?>`no puedo meter esa constante dentro de un echo ya que no es una varible.

Saludos

Comment: Que sucede al hacer click en "MAS INFO"? Abres un modal para mostrar la información? Redireccionas a otra pagina?

Comment: Redirecciono a otra página dinamica, según id muestra diferente resultado

Comment: Escribe un par de ejemplos de cómo quedaría toda la línea del `<a></a>` en distintos casos, por ejemplo `<a href="detalle-vivienda.php?ID=7" class="botonMasInfo">MÁS INFO</a>` ... `<a href="detalle-vivienda.php?ID=7" class="botonMasInfo">MORE INFO</a>` .. a ver si se entiende mejor qué buscas.

Comment: @AdoPeder acabo de modificar la pregunta a ver si se entiendo mejor

Answer (score 1):

No veo ningun problema si lo que deseas es colocar una web con distintos idiomas para reemplazar el texto de tu **eco**.

Puedes hacer dos cosas;

1) Reemplaza el texto por una variable y lo coloca el echo de esta forma, entonces lo que cambiaras es el contenido de la variable:

```
$texto ="MÁS INFO"; 
echo "<a href=\"detalle-vivienda.php?ID=$viID\" class=\"botonMasInfo\">$texto</a>";
```

2)  Separa la etiqueta anchor  en dos echos y coloca un tercero dentro de los dos

```
echo "<a href=\"detalle-vivienda.php?ID=$viID\" class=\"botonMasInfo\">";
echo "MÁS INFO";
echo "</a>";
```

El codigo se ejecutara de igual forma porque has cerrado el vinculo al final.

Comment: Gracias @Alexander Rodrigez , eso que me pones no me vale, ya que lo que necesito meter ahí es esto `<?php echo anadidosRecientes; ?>`. Una pregunta es mejor para los idiomas y más teniendo en cuenta que luego hay que hacer algunas cosas dinamicas, es mejor en `constantes` o en `variables` ??? Saludos